# Can @findby annotation be used in an interface with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, findby

Lets see below code:

```
public interface HomePageObjects {

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@class='_2zrpKA']")
    WebElement UsernameField ;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@class='_2zrpKA _3v41xv']")
    WebElement PswdField ;

}

public class HomePageTests implements HomePageObjects {

    WebDriver Driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void initpage() {
        Driver = LaunchBrowser.Driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(Driver, this); 
        System.out.println(UsernameField + " " + Driver);
    }

}
```

This code compiles fine, but it is not able to initialize webelements, does any one has an explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code for the [PageFactory class](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/PageFactory.java), check the `initElements` method.

```
public static void initElements(FieldDecorator decorator, Object page) {
    Class<?> proxyIn = page.getClass();
    while (proxyIn != Object.class) {
      proxyFields(decorator, page, proxyIn);
      proxyIn = proxyIn.getSuperclass();
    }
  }
```

The `proxyIn.getSuperclass()` returns the superclass of the pageobject ignoring the interface. So in your case it goes from `HomePageTests.class` to `Object.class`. Thus the webelements in the interface will remain uninitialized.
You can look at using an abstract class instead which is a better idea for storing state.

Comment: Thanks, i had a similar thought. Having said that, the reason of creating pageobject interface is to implement as many pageobjects as possible. I want to access webelement without specifying classname.
Could you please suggest some workaround?

Answer (score 0):

In Java, fields that are declared as members of an interface are implicitly `static` and `final`. Therefore, these members are not part of your object instance and therefore `PageFactory.initElements` doesn't initialize them.

The same should happen also without using an interface - all `@findBy` annotations on static members will be ignored.

Comment: In second para, do you mean static and final?, If yes, then this is also correct, but the first one is what I was actually looking for.